# Laravel SQL statement is returning null

Tags: sql, mysql, laravel, count, laravel-blade

i am new to Laravel and i am working on a blog/post project with likes and comments.

Now i would like to display/count all likes from all post that was made by a user.
So for example: user 1 made post 1 and user 2, user 3 liked post 1, should be 2 likes displayed on user 1 profile page. That is not the case right now and i don't know where i messed up with the SQL statement below.

[Blogs table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ3Mn.png)
[Likes table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DhUW.png)

Controller:

```
    public function getProfilePage()
    {

        $user = Auth::user();
        $blog = Blog::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
        $likes = Like::where('likeable_id', $blog)->get();
        $comments = DB::table('comments')->where('user_id', $user->id)->get();

        return view('auth.profile', compact('user', 'blog', 'likes', 'comments'));
    }
```

And in Blade file i count($likes)

now i know the problem is somewhere in $blog, but to my knowledge this statement should be correct. Still it's returning 0 likes.

Models:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Contracts\Likeable;
use App\Models\Concerns\Likes;
use Usamamuneerchaudhary\Commentify\Traits\Commentable;

class Blog extends Model implements Likeable
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Likes;
    use Commentable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'beschrijving',
        'image',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Like extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class)->withDefault();
    }

    public function likeable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of my head I'm not sure whether there isnt a conversion which will take care of it, but it might be possible you need to specify blog `$blog->id`.

```
$blog = Blog::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
$likes = Like::where('likeable_id', $blog->id)->get();
```

instead of

```
$blog = Blog::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
$likes = Like::where('likeable_id', $blog)->get();
```

Comment: Then i get a error "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance."

Comment: Oh, that make sense. `Blog::where('user_id', $user->id)->get()` will return collection containing one model. But still a collection. You want only the one model itself. I updated the answer. You need also to change the Blog line to `$blog = Blog::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();`

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are using a polymorphic relationship between blogs and likes. Check that you have made this relationship correctly in the models. The documentation for it is here. [Laravel relationship documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-model-structure)

You should have a morph many function in your blog model and morphto in your likeable. The comments in the example and the documentation explains it well

Comment: i am not entirely sure, but i uploaded my models above